# custom navigationitem titleview wrong frame

Tags: ios, navigationitem, titleview

hi i just make a custom navigationitem title view, but it looks a bit wrong.

here is the custom view ,it base on a uiview

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        _titleLabel=[[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
        [self addSubview:_titleLabel];

        _actionButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [self addSubview:_actionButton];
        [_actionButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_cal_right"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    return self;
}
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [_titleLabel sizeToFit];
    [_actionButton sizeToFit];

    CGFloat height=44;//MAX(_titleLabel.frame.size.height, _actionButton.frame.size.height);
    self.frame=CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                          0,
                          _titleLabel.frame.size.width+_actionButton.frame.size.width+kMargin,
                          height);
    _titleLabel.frame=CGRectMake(0,
                                 (height-_titleLabel.frame.size.height)/2,
                                 _titleLabel.frame.size.width,
                                 _titleLabel.frame.size.height);
    _actionButton.frame=CGRectMake(_titleLabel.frame.size.width+kMargin,
                                   (height-_actionButton.frame.size.height)/2,
                                   _actionButton.frame.size.width,
                                   _actionButton.frame.size.height);
}
```

but when app run, it likes that, the title isn't in the centre 

screen shot is here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQVLr.png

Answer (score 0):

set titleLabel backgroundColor as `[UIColor clearColor]`;